# Custom Column with multiple column references in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dataset, powerquery, populate

Below is the dataset,
[image]

I would like to add a new column at the end of the dataset as "Covid No Vaccination Dose". This column will include of the populated data from the Covid Vaccination Dose 1, Covid Vaccination Dose 2, Covid Vaccination - Full Dose and Covid Vaccination - Booster Dose.

So basically in this scenario, there are few workers with No vaccination doses of any of the vaccines and has been identified by the said above columns.

I'm struggling to populate the answer "No" from the above said 4 Covid Vaccination columns to one Single Column which will be named as "Covid No Vaccination Dose".

Really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in powerquery with the data

Add column ... custom column ...  set the column name to Covid No Vaccination Dose

and use formula similar to:

```
= if [#"Covid Vaccination - Dose 1"]="No" and [#"Covid Vaccination - Dose 2"]="No" and [#"Covid Vaccination - Full Dose"]="No" and [#"Covid Vaccination - Booster"]="No" then "No" else "Yes"
```

rather then type the [...] parts, I suggest you click on them in the right

Comment: Thank you for your reply @horseyride.
However, I get an error code saying "Token Eof expected".

Comment: Do you think that writing a measure would help me better showcase? Since I'm trying to show the "Total of Covid No Vaccination Dose" using a "Card Visualization"?

Comment: then you are using the code wrong. Edit your question and paste in the entirety of the code from home ...advanced editor...   I also noticed now I dropped the ending " after the word YES on the formula, now fixed in answer above. Check if that is in your version

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it appears that the cells will contain either `Yes` or `No`.  That being the case, you can use a custom column with a formula similar to the following:

```
=List.Last(List.Sort(List.Distinct({[Covid Vaccination Dose 1],[Covid Vaccination Dose 2],[#"Covid Vaccination - Full Dose"],[#"Covid Vaccination - Booster Dose"]})))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ron Rosenfeld.
However, I get an error code for the entire column.

Comment: Do you think that writing a measure would help me better showcase? Since I'm trying to show the "Total of Covid No Vaccination Dose" using a "Card Visualization"?

Comment: @CYBERBE1NG  *I get an error code for the entire column.*   You probably made mistakes when you tried to adapt the supplied code to your actual data.

Comment: @CYBERBE1NG *writing a measure*  I have no idea.  Suggest you try it and see.